# Limit, log rule

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I have couple of question on this part of equation -

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{ 7 \cdot \sqrt{n}}{\log(n)}- \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n\cdot \log(n)} &=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{7 \cdot \sqrt{n}}{\log(n)}-0 \tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{7 n}{2 \sqrt{n}} \tag{2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{7}{2} \sqrt{n} = \infty
\end{align}

> 1 - How does $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n \log(n)}$$ evaluates to 0? Is it something to do with one of those limit rules that says limit x approaches to infinity 1/x^n = 0?
>
> 2 - How does log n in the equation evaluate to 2n^(1/2)?

Thanks

Comment: startet setting it in $\LaTeX$ will fix the rest give me some minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is hard to read the first part, i guess that it is the numbered stuff that is the question.

The first one as $\log(n)$ is greater 1 as $n>3$ we know that 
$$\frac{1}{n} \geq \frac{1}{\log(n) \cdot n} \geq 0$$

For the second questoin they use L'hospital, as 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \log(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$ and 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x}= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$ 
we have 
$$7\cdot \frac{x}{2\sqrt{x}}= \frac{7}{2} \sqrt{x}$$

Comment: Thanks for editing as well as for the good explanation!One question though how do you know n is > 3? Is it from natural log value?

Comment: @Andy in fact it is for $n> e$ but as it is for natural numbers i thought 3 would be a more intuitive bound. As the log is strict monotone increasing and $\ln(e)=1$ you see it

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n\log n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/n}{\log n}
$$
Numerator and denominator both go to zero, so L'Hopital's rule:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/n}{\log n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{-1/n^2}{1/n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1}{n} = 0
$$